# how can I push new project on different branch on github

Tags: git, github

I want to create a repo which will have different branches and every different branch will contain a new project. And I want to push every project from my cmd.
Like this repo:
https://github.com/Learn-with-Sumit/think-in-a-redux-way

How can I do that?
Is there any videos or documentation that you can provide me?

Answer (score 0):

Use `git checkout -b <new-branch>` it will simultaneously create and checks out a `<new-branch>` and then you can add your changes there.
Then you have to add,commit, push each branch into your remote repository as in
`git push origin <branch-1>`
`git push origin <branch-2>`

And you can do this accordingly to your branches then go to your GitHub or whatever you use you can see new branches being created